# getting complex-valued Jacobian Matrix using NonLinearModel.fit in matlab

Tags: matlab, regression

I am trying to use the `NonLinearModel.fit()` function in Matlab to regress two variables. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error using internal.stats.getscheffeparam>ValidateParameters
(line 182)
If non-empty, JW must be a numeric, real matrix.

Error in internal.stats.getscheffeparam (line 110)
[J,VF,VP,JW,Intopt,TolSVD,TolE,VQ,usingJ] =
ValidateParameters(J,VF,VP,JW,Intopt,TolSVD,TolE,VQ,allowedIntopt);

Error in nlinfit (line 340)
    sch =
    internal.stats.getscheffeparam('WeightedJacobian',J(~nans,:),'Intopt','observation','VQ',VQ);

Error in NonLinearModel/fitter (line 1121)
               [model.Coefs,~,J_r,model.CoefficientCovariance,model.MSE,model.ErrorModelInfo,~]
            = ...

Error in classreg.regr.FitObject/doFit (line 219)
        model = fitter(model);

Error in NonLinearModel.fit (line 1484)
        model = doFit(model);

Error in getMatrix (line 101)
    nlm =
    NonLinearModel.fit(regressorMatrix',temp2',modelfun,beta0);
```

My `regressorMatrix` is 2-by-N (so the transpose is N-by-2), `temp2'` is N-by-1, and `beta0` and `model` are given by:

```
model =@(b,x)b(1).*x(:,1).*x(:,2).^b(2);
beta0=[.14 .6];
nlm = NonLinearModel.fit(regressorMatrix',temp2',model,beta0);
```

Could someone please help me in figuring out what is causing this error?

EDIT: ok, no help so far so I will try to be more specific. I know that this error is referring to the weighted Jacobian matrix. I am just not sure why this Jacobian would not be real-valued.

Here are the first few rows of my regressor matrix:

```
regressorMatrix =

1.0e+07 *

0.000000000776613   3.762601240855837
0.000000001683014   3.762601240855837
0.000000001496807   3.762601240855837
0.000000000753495   3.762601240855837
```

and my response matrix:

```
temp2 =
-0.011811061934317
0.987582922964869
0.010621342764736
0.135001167018444
0.091950680609212
```

I can see that something is wrong here (the orders of magnitude in col2 of my regressor matrix are off. I will fix this and get back with an explanation if it turns out to the the cause. I am also working on printing out J. and JW

EDIT2: 
I was able to print out JW before the error occurs and discovered that JW is a Nx2 complex matrix. So the specific reason the error is occurring is that the weighted Jacobian matrix is not real valued. Not sure why...

Comment: What is `NonLinearFit`? It doesn't appear to be part of standard Matlab or common toolbox. Are you using [`NonLinearModel.fit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinearmodel.fit.html) or [`nlinfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html) maybe? Please show your code where you actually call this function.

Comment: @horchler, yes you are right I meant NonLinearModel.fit. I edited my code accordingly and added the line where I call the function.

Comment: @Amir it's best not to go on tag-adding sprees until you hit 2k rep

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I found that the answer to this problem is quite obvious. I didn't realize that some of the values for one of my regressor variables was going negative sometimes. This lead (jumping a few steps ahead) to a complex Jacobian.